# Mapbox Studio - How to slice a rail line shapefile tileset into different parts?

Tags: shapefile, mapbox

Mapbox newbie here. I am trying to build a railway map and when its security systems are expected to be completed. So I have added a rail line shapefile as a tileset to a Mapbpx Studio style. I want to create a map where different parts of the line have different colors and when clicked, present a different date. But I am at a loss. I just get a continuous line and that's it.

Wondering how should I go about it since I can not understand how to slice the tileset, which is a line, into different sections, and add data to it.